# How to debug JNI which be called by multi-java thread in Linux

Tags: java, java-native-interface, gdb

I create a Java class which contains multi-thread, each thread call a different JNI interface. I try to use gdb -p (pid is the java process id) to debug the JNI. However, I can't find the specific JNI interface correspond to which thread. How can I debug JNI code in gdb in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply connect with gdb to JVM process.

Start your sample code

```
java
```

Use jps to list Java processes

```
jps
```

Connect gdb to process

```
gdb /proc/PID/exe PID
```

Debug the code

```
jps
9340 Jps
9278 HelloWorld
...
gdb /proc/9278/exe 9278
...
(gdb) break mode_1
Breakpoint 1 at 0x2b8126cd97b6: file c/recipeNo024_HelloWorld.c, line 6.
(gdb) break mode_2
Breakpoint 2 at 0x2b8126cd97c8: file c/recipeNo024_HelloWorld.c, line 10.
(gdb) break mode_3
Breakpoint 3 at 0x2b8126cd97da: file c/recipeNo024_HelloWorld.c, line 14.
(gdb) cont
...
...
[Switching to Thread 0x2b81270dc700 (LWP 9337)]

Breakpoint 2, mode_2 () at c/recipeNo024_HelloWorld.c:10
10              printf("Mode 2\n");
(gdb) cont
Continuing.
[Switching to Thread 0x2b8126fdb700 (LWP 9335)]

Breakpoint 1, mode_1 () at c/recipeNo024_HelloWorld.c:6
6               printf("Mode 1\n");
(gdb) cont
Continuing.
[Switching to Thread 0x2b81271dd700 (LWP 9338)]

Breakpoint 3, mode_3 () at c/recipeNo024_HelloWorld.c:14
14              printf("Mode 3\n");
(gdb) cont
```

You can find sample code for this example here:

https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipes/recipeNo024

You can also find demo video on debugging using CLion here:

https://youtu.be/8Cjeq4l5COU